# To parse json data with Gson, why "\" backslash is ignored?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I use retrofit 2.0 to get user info from backend, and Gson to parse json data.

Some path info like **`"/some/image/folders/"`**, the data I received is changed to **`"\/some\/image\/folders\/"`**, backslash is added in front of each slash. We just put aside this changes.

After I received that path info, okhttp debug log show the string value is **`"\/some\/image\/folders\/"`**, but when I log the response.body() in retrofit, the string is changed to **`"/some/image/folders/"`**.

So I wonder know:

1. The changes from **`"\/some\/image\/folders\/"`** to **`"/some/image/folders/"`** is Gson's behavior or retrofit's?
2. When that changes happended?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The "\" is a escape character, so if you write "/home" when you print the output you will get "/home"

It seems to be Gson behavior: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/356

Comment: "/" is no need to be escaped.

Comment: Where do you get that path info, in a request or inside your logic (settings file or a controller) ? 

If you get from a user request could be part of the management of the request params.

If you get from your internal logic, probably you have something that is escaping that character

Comment: The path info is received from backend, backend's dev language is php. The changes from "/some/image/folders/" to "\/some\/image\/folders\/" is no need to be concerned, its backend's logic.

Comment: It seems to be Gson behavior: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/356

Comment: Tks. All is under json standard.